# ItemAdded remote event receiver will fire twice if i create a new list item + attach file to it

Tags: development, csom, custom-list, remote-event-receiver

I have a custom list inside a SharePoint online communication site. and i have attached an ItemAdded remote event receiver to the custom list. now if i create a new list item and i do not attach any file to it >> save the item >> the ItemAdded RER will run once which is fine.

But if i create a new list item and inside the create form i also attach a file >> save the item >> then the RER will run twice. so is there a way to prevent this behavior? or how i can check if the item added is for the list item and not for the attachment ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to trigger remote event receiver when adding attachments,you could use an attachment was added to the list event directly.
[image]
And you could get event type by this way:

```
properties.EventType
```

Source:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/handle-list-item-events-in-the-provider-hosted-add-in

Comment: i want to fire the RER only when adding a new list item.. also the multiple events will be of type ItemAdded